# Creating a trigger on aspnet_membership makes login fail

Tags: t-sql, webforms, asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke

I'm doing some maintance on an older web application where we have 2 DB's. One for the WWW frontend (DotNetNuke) and another for the admin backend. Both of the applications use aspnet_membership for users, and we want to sync logins between the app's. I thought we'd do this with a trigger, but logins starts failing when I add the trigger.

```
USE dnnTicket
GO 

CREATE TRIGGER update_membership ON dbo.aspnet_Membership 
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON   
    IF (trigger_nestlevel() > 1) RETURN --Make sure a similar trigger on the other db don't cause infinite loops. 
    UPDATE ticket4you.dbo.aspnet_Membership SET 
              [Password] = INSERTED.[Password],
              PasswordFormat = INSERTED.PasswordFormat,
              PasswordSalt = INSERTED.PasswordSalt,
              MobilePIN = INSERTED.MobilePIN,
              Email = INSERTED.Email,
              LoweredEmail = INSERTED.LoweredEmail,
              PasswordQuestion = INSERTED.PasswordQuestion,
              PasswordAnswer = INSERTED.PasswordAnswer ,
              IsApproved = INSERTED.IsApproved ,
              IsLockedOut = INSERTED.IsLockedOut ,
              CreateDate = INSERTED.CreateDate ,
              LastLoginDate = INSERTED.LastLoginDate ,
              LastPasswordChangedDate = INSERTED.LastPasswordChangedDate,
              LastLockoutDate = INSERTED.LastLockoutDate ,
              FailedPasswordAttemptCount = INSERTED.FailedPasswordAttemptCount ,
              FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = INSERTED.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart ,
              FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = INSERTED.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount ,
              FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = INSERTED.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart 
    FROM  INSERTED 
    WHERE ticket4you.[dbo].aspnet_Membership.UserId = INSERTED.userID 
SET NOCOUNT OFF 
GO
```

With this trigger in the DB logins using the dnnTicket db fails.

I traced the SQL server activity as best I could and found a very strange difference in the trace from when the query is run in the web server to when I manualy run the same query from SMMS.

[image: This is the trace I get when the login is run from DotNetNuke]

[image: This is the trace I get when running the same query from SQL server management studio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance the trigger looks ok.

I would start by checking that both applications have the same configuration for the membership provider, and the same machine keys.

Then I would look for any error message that may be getting recorded.  The DNN event viewer, (and log4net log file in 6.0) are good sources.  If there is nothing I would use sql profiler to look for any messages related to trigger/login process.

Also can you describe the failure in more detail?  Does the trigger prevent logging in to both systems, or can you log into system A, but then not system B, or you can only ever access one system?

Comment: The configuration is not equal between the app's. (diffrent DB's for one) and what do you mean with machine key's?

Comment: DNN event viewer has not logged ANY error messages related to login, event though it's set up to do so. Log4net i don't know what you mean with. Sql profiler reports no error. The error message i get is: "Innlogging feilet". I'm unable to find this error text in the solution, might it be somewhere in the DB?

Comment: The membership providers need all the same settings except for db.  The machine key (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) is used to encrypt/hash the passwords, if it is not the same in both applications, your passwords will not work.

Comment: The error was missing rights for the DB login that DNN ran under. Unfortantly the error was suppressed by DNN, no log's whatsoever. I found it when I added the correct errors to SQL server profiler.

Comment: I don't understand how DNN could work at all if the credentials were incorrect.  If DNN was running then it's credentials were correct, and the missing credentials were required from something outside the core of DNN, hence no error logged in DNN.

Comment: Dnn had full rights to the dnnticket db, but no rights to the ticket4you db referd to in the trigger above. Thus login failed because loggin in causes the last loggin date to be uppdated. This led to the trigger fireing and the sp trying to log the user inn failed with an access denied error. This error was suppresed by dnn, and a generic login failed was given the user. By dropping the trigger i could then login to dnn and find that no errors where logged.